# Multiple Inheritance in Java since All classes extend from Object class?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a simple question:

If I declare a class A - means this class in implicitly inheriting from Object Class.

Now If class B inherits from class A

is this Class B also not Inheriting from Object class ?

If yes, does that mean writing the keyword 'extends' some how override the implicit inheritance ( from class Object) ?

Comment: Here you will get better answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897244/multiple-inheritance-and-class-object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All classes extend form `Object`, either implicitly or explicitly, directly or indirectly, the whole class hierarchy in Java ends up pointing at `Object`, which is at the root. For instance, when you write this:

```
public class MyClass extends Object {
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
public class MyClass {
```

And if we have this:

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass {
```

Then `MySubClass` extends from `MyClass` which extends from `Object`. It's a transitive inheritance relationship, and it occurs in only one direction: at no point in the hierarchy it will be possible that a single class extends from more than one class - that's why we say that in Java we have single-inheritance (as opposed to: multiple-inheritance.)

Answer (score 4):

`A` inherits from `Object` and `B` inherits from `A`. So you have 3 levels of inheritance (2 explicit). There is no multiple inheritance here.

```
`Object`
    |
   `A`
    |
   `B`
```

Comment: So B class is not inheriting from Object direct !!hmm ....

Comment: @GV1234 It doesn't need to since `A` is extending it.

Answer (score 1):

When you 'extends', your class gets everything from the base class and adds extra stuff. So, if A extends Object, you've got all of Object in A. If B extends A, it gets all of A which also has all of Object. So, B now has Object, A and anything in B itself.

Multiple inheritence is when you extend a class from many things at once:

```
public class M extends SomeBase, AndAnotherBase {
```

This isn't allowed in Java. It adds complication in languages that do allow it because you can end up with class M being comprised of SomeBase, AndAnotherBase... and if they both already derive from Object... M would have 2 Objects in it.  This starts to get tricky to deal with as you have to know which Object within M you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically mention inheriting from `Object`, but if you are asking about inheritance in general between children and grandchildren, then yes, `B` will inherit from all predecessors.

```
public class A{
   public String getAString(){
       return "Hello from A";
   }
 }


public class B extends A {
    public String getBString(){
        return  getAString() + " and Hello from B.";
    }
}


 public class C extends B{
 }

 public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         C c = new C();
         //                 Inherited from A         Inherited from B
         System.out.println(c.getAString() + "..." + c.getBString());
     }
 }
```

This gives

```
Hello from A...Hello from A and Hello from B.
```

Notice `C` has no code in the class body.  All functionality is being inherited.

Inheriting from `Object` is a little special in that it is implicit.  There is no need to say `extends Object` on any class -- it's redundant.  But the inheritance mechanism is no different.